# Go Into Exercise

Tags: prepositions, idioms

It seems that one can write:

> He ***went into*** action.
>   He ***went into*** seclusion.

Could I then write:

> He ***went into*** exercise.
>   ?

Comment: Er, no, typically you can't. Though, you could write, *"He went **in to** exercise".* :)

Answer (score 2):

In non-locative uses of *go into* the object is a ordinarily either a state or an occupation or a long-sustained activity: *hiding*, *business*, *politics*, *combat*, *retirement*.

*Exercise* is for most people a short-term activity, so it doesn't really fit. However, it might be acceptable in a context where *exercise* meant a long-term regimen: *He went into exercise to improve his poor health.*

Be careful to distinguish *GO into NOUN* from *GO in(side) to VERB*, where *to VERB* is an infinitive of purpose:

> He bicycled to the gym and went in to exercise.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't say *he went into exercise*. It sounds strange, and it's not clear what it is supposed to mean. Does it mean he started to exercise on one particular occasion, or did he started exercising habitually?

Below are the results from [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) for `[PPHS1] went into [N*]` (he/she went into noun). The numbers on the right are the number of hits.

I think that list suggests that for "he/she went into X", then X can be a location ("he went into town"), a career ("he went into politics"), or some long lived or momentous state of being ("he went into prison", "he went into convulsions").

I would guess that *exercise* is too much of an incidental and transitory activity to say that you went into it.

> SHE WENT INTO LABOR   38
>   HE WENT INTO BUSINESS 16
>   HE WENT INTO TOWN 15
>   HE WENT INTO EXILE    12
>   SHE WENT INTO TOWN    11
>   HE WENT INTO POLITICS 7
>   SHE WENT INTO SURGERY 6
>   HE WENT INTO KUWAIT   5
>   HE WENT INTO SURGERY  4
>   HE WENT INTO COURT    4
>   HE WENT INTO REHAB    4
>   HE WENT INTO PRISON   4
>   HE WENT INTO OFFICE   4
>   SHE WENT INTO SHOCK   4
>   HE WENT INTO NEW  3
>   HE WENT INTO PARTNERSHIP  3
>   SHE WENT INTO REHAB   3
>   SHE WENT INTO THERAPY 3
>   HE WENT INTO CONVULSIONS  2
>   HE WENT INTO COMPUTERS    2
>   HE WENT INTO ADVERTISING  2
>   HE WENT INTO ACTION   2
>   HE WENT INTO AREAS    2
>   HE WENT INTO DECLINE  2
>   HE WENT INTO DEBT 2
>   HE WENT INTO GOVERNMENT   2
>   HE WENT INTO LAW  2
>   HE WENT INTO OVERDRIVE    2
>   HE WENT INTO ORBIT    2
>   HE WENT INTO PRACTICE 2
>   HE WENT INTO TERRITORY    2
>   SHE WENT INTO BUSINESS    2
>   SHE WENT INTO COUNSELING  2
>   HE WENT INTO WATER    1
>   HE WENT INTO VIRGINIA 1
>   HE WENT INTO TUINEI   1
>   HE WENT INTO TREATMENT    1
>   HE WENT INTO TRAINING 1
>   HE WENT INTO TEACHING 1
>   HE WENT INTO TALKS    1
>   HE WENT INTO STASIS   1
>   HE WENT INTO SPACE    1
>   HE WENT INTO SOUTH    1
>   HE WENT INTO SHOES    1
>   HE WENT INTO SHOCK    1
>   HE WENT INTO SEMI-RETIREMENT  1
>   HE WENT INTO SECOND   1
>   HE WENT INTO SECLUSION    1
>   HE WENT INTO SATURDAY 1
>   HE WENT INTO SALES    1
>   HE WENT INTO REMISSION    1
>   HE WENT INTO RAPTURES 1
>   HE WENT INTO RAGES    1
>   HE WENT INTO RADIO    1
>   HE WENT INTO POP  1
>   HE WENT INTO PEARL    1
>   HE WENT INTO PANIC    1
>   HE WENT INTO PANAMA   1
>   HE WENT INTO OCCULTATION  1
>   HE WENT INTO NORMANDY 1
>   HE WENT INTO LAMBETH  1
>   HE WENT INTO NEUROSURGERY 1
>   HE WENT INTO MULTISYSTEM  1
>   HE WENT INTO MULLER   1
>   HE WENT INTO MOTION   1
>   HE WENT INTO MORTGAGE 1
>   HE WENT INTO MINI-EXILE   1
>   HE WENT INTO MEISTER  1
>   HE WENT INTO MEDICINE 1
>   HE WENT INTO MAY  1
>   HE WENT INTO MATTIE   1
>   HE WENT INTO MACKIE   1
>   HE WENT INTO LUNCH    1
>   HE WENT INTO LOS  1
>   HE WENT INTO LIHUC    1
>   HE WENT INTO KROGER   1
>   HE WENT INTO KOREA    1
>   HE WENT INTO JOURNALISM   1
>   HE WENT INTO JACOBS   1
>   HE WENT INTO IRAQ 1
>   HE WENT INTO INSURANCE    1
>   HE WENT INTO HIBERNATION  1
>   HE WENT INTO GEORGE   1
>   HE WENT INTO FORECLOSURE  1
>   HE WENT INTO FILMS    1
>   HE WENT INTO FARMING  1
>   HE WENT INTO FALL 1
>   HE WENT INTO EGBE 1
>   HE WENT INTO ECLIPSE  1
>   HE WENT INTO DIE  1
>   HE WENT INTO DENNY    1
>   HE WENT INTO DAWSON   1
>   HE WENT INTO CUSTODY  1
>   HE WENT INTO CRISIS   1
>   HE WENT INTO ALIZABETH    1
>   HE WENT INTO ALCOHOL  1
>   HE WENT INTO COMBAT   1
>   HE WENT INTO CODY 1
>   HE WENT INTO COACHING 1
>   HE WENT INTO CHEMICALS    1

Answer (score 0):

Yes that could be correct. It's just a writing style. Some writers have odd writing styles, even a few have improper grammar. I don't hear it a lot though. I would usually say

> He started to exercise.

I suggest you use popular phrases, or else others will think that you have weird grammar (but personally, I won't care).

Comment: "He went into exercise" is grammatically correct, but extremely awkward (though I can't explain why). "He started to exercise" is much more natural.